# Unable to open database with SQLiteAssetHelper

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am using `SQLite` Database to get the product name, quantity, price but when  ever i press add_to_cart button, it force closes.

[This is what my debugger says, how to debug this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sy1Zx.png)

```
public void addToCart(Order order){
   SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
   String query = String.format("INSERT INTO OrderDetail(Productid,ProductName,Quantity,Price) VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s');",
    order.getProductid(),
    order.getProductName(),
    order.getQuantity(),
    order.getPrice());
    db.execSQL(query);
}

btncart = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.btncart);
btncart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       //line 49// 
        new Database(FoodDetails.this).addToCart(new Order(
            foodId,
            currentFood.getName(),
            numberButton.getNumber(),
            currentFood.getPrice()
        ));
        Toast.makeText(FoodDetails.this,"Added to cart",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

This is the given `StackTrace`:

> at com.k.menu.Database.Database.addToCart(Database.java:54)
>                                                                      at com.k.menu.FoodDetails$1.onClick(FoodDetails.java:49) These two are
>   the errors i got from logcat
>
> ```
> 1-19 19:43:14.767 9304-9304/com.k.menu E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                       Process: com.k.menu, PID: 9304
>                                                       com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper$SQLiteAssetException: Missing databases/eatitDb.db file (or .zip, .gz archive) in assets, or target folder not writable
>                                                           at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
>                                                           at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:347)
>                                                           at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:321)
>                                                           at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.copyDatabaseFromAssets(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:436)
>                                                           at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.createOrOpenDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:400)
>                                                           at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:176)
>                                                           at com.k.menu.Database.Database.addToCart(Database.java:54)
>                                                           at com.k.menu.FoodDetails$1.onClick(FoodDetails.java:49)
>                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
>                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
>                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
> ```

The below link has my application database and food details https://www.dropbox.com/sh/j2j4umz5wv2o7t4/AACIExIYT24SjiYlxbZ0Ut24a?dl=0

Comment: Please use titles that are more descriptive of the exact issues, rather than just variations on "How do I debug this?".

Comment: post your database helper class

Comment: @jitendrapurohit sir its in above link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> SQLiteAssetException:
>   Missing databases/eatitDb.db file (or .zip, .gz archive) in assets, or
>   target folder not writable

Means exactly that either the file **eatitDb.db** is not in the **assets/databases** directory or for some reason the target folder is not writeable.

So 1) check that the file copied into the assets/databases file is named eatitDb.db. If it isn't the copy it into that location, clear the App's data or uninstall the App (probably not required) and then rerun the App.

2) If the file is located then ensure that it is copied to somewhere where it will be writeable (although if it weren't then you couldn't copy it) and that you aren't changing the file permsissions.

---

#### Note re `getReadableDatabase`

Changing `getReadableDatabase` to `getWriteableDatabase` will not resolve the problem. As `getReadableDatabase` will get a writeable database if it can: as per :-

> Create and/or open a database. This will be the same object returned by getWritableDatabase() unless some problem, such as a full
>   disk, requires the database to be opened read-only. In that case, a
>   read-only database object will be returned. If the problem is fixed, a
>   future call to getWritableDatabase() may succeed, in which case the
>   read-only database object will be closed and the read/write object
>   will be returned in the future.

[getReadableDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getreadableDatabase%28%29)

Comment: @KarthikN I'd appreciate you marking this as the correct answer rather than the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

try using getWritableDatabase instead of getReadableDatabase.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase()

Comment: `getReadableDatabase` will get a writeable database unless it cannot. If you follow your link and look at `getReadableDatabase` it says :-*Create and/or open a database. This will be the same object returned by getWritableDatabase() unless some problem, such as a full disk, requires the database to be opened read-only. In that case, a read-only database object will be returned. If the problem is fixed, a future call to getWritableDatabase() may succeed, in which case the read-only database object will be closed and the read/write object will be returned in the future.*

Answer (score 0):

Check your application file structure and see if the database.db file is placed in the right directory.

Where to place the database file?

Place your db file in /src/main/assets/databases/your_db_file.db (this file must have extension of .db or .zip)

Answer (score 0):

kindly change folder name from database to databases